# My C# win form application internally calls a batch script how do I hide it from the end user while exporting in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file

Inside my C# project, there is a folder called "scripts" that has my batch scripts inside it however while exporting the project I don't want the end-user to tamper with those scripts or make modifications. I would really appreciate it, if there was a way to hide these scripts from the user completely. OR Any other way that could possibly mask their existence completely.

Comment: I would suggest to get rid of the bat files entirely and reimplement them in your  C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed the Batch files as resources. Save it to a temporary file, run it and delete the temporary file after it ran.

Depending on the content of the batch file, it might be possible to run the programs called by the batch file in C# directly.

There are also tools like [Bat2Exe](https://bat2exe.net/) which convert the batch file into an executable, hiding that it once was a BAT file. Make sure to check the license conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, converting it into .exe worked for me, really appreciate it. I was thinking about using c# however the API that I'd need for it is sadly no longer maintained, so batch was my only option here. Never mind though since my problem is solved by converting the file.